# Objective-C Access Specific Item in Plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist

I have created an app, and I am trying to access a URL that is stored in a plist file. At this state I am just trying to log the contents out. I am aware similar questions have been asked before, but I am asking specifically to my scenario how to I access `Item 0`. I am trying to access `Item 0` inside `InternalViaSafari` this manifests itself inside the `URLValidator` and then that inside the `Root`. The code I have so far is:
[image: plist file]

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plist-file-name" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary* plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSString* name = [plist valueForKeyPath:@"URLValidator.InternalViaSafari"];
NSLog(name);
```

Comment: beter use nsuserdefalt than plist.

Comment: This is not possible because i need multiple plists for various config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `keyPath` like that for this as far as I know. `InternalViaSafari` is not a property of `URLValidator` dictionary. What's more `InternalViaSafari` is an `Array` not a `String` in your plist.

In order to get this string you'd need something like this :

```
NSArray *internalViaSafari = plist[@"URLValidator"][@"InternalViaSafari"];
NSString *name = internalViaSafari.firstObject;
```

What happens here, is that you get the value under the `URLValidator` key from your `plist` dictionary. This value is also a `Dictionary` (this can be clearly seen in the plist screenshot you shared), so you get the value under the `InternalViaSafari` key. This value is in turn an `Array`, which has `Strings` as its elements. In this example I extracted the first entry from this array.

Comment: I receive an error from this `Property firstObject not found on object of type id_Nullable`

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo! Too much Swift lately, and I forgot that you need to prefix string literals with `@` in Objective-C :)